# html input regex pattern not working

Tags: html, regex

I have the following code:

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" " pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+"></input> </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+"> </input> </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Voucher: <input type="text" name="voucher" value="" pattern="^[0-9]{5}+[-]+[0-9]{5}+[-]+[A-Z]{2}*"></input> </label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

---

The above code is my code, first name and last name are all working, the problem is the voucher input does not check the pattern I wanted, it should look like "12345-67890-AB".

Comment: You don't need the `+` because you are already saying you need 5 characters

Comment: you don't need `^` at the beginning of the regex (nor `$` at the end). [the pattern attribute of HTML forms implies that](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
^[0-9]{5}[-]+[0-9]{5}[-]+[A-Z]{2}
```

http://regexr.com/3b338

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `+`s and final `*` and add a `$` at the end:

```
^[0-9]{5}[-][0-9]{5}[-][A-Z]{2}$
```

Or since the [`pattern` attribute does not require anchoring](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute), you can also use

```
[0-9]{5}[-][0-9]{5}[-][A-Z]{2}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI9gG0/4)

Explanation:

- `^` - Beginning of a string (not necessary since the `pattern` string is anchored)
- `[0-9]{5}` - Exactly 5 digits
- `[-]` - Exactly 1 hyphen
- `[0-9]{5}` - Exactly 5 digits
- `[-]` - Exactly 1 hyphen
- `[A-Z]{2}` - Exactly 2 uppercase English letters.
- `$` - End of string (again, can be omitted since the pattern is anchored).

Comment: @iouhammi: This regex is very generic, it will work for JavaScript and most other flavors.

Comment: Thank you! this one works as well ! thanks for the explanation too !